# In FileLoader.php line 168: Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Symfony 3 Framework was working fine but this sudden error appears,

```
In FileLoader.php line 168:
```

The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Resources\config\routing" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\php\hamad\vendor
  \composer/../../src/AppBundle\Resources\config\routing.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the cl
  ass name or namespace probably has a typo in C:\xampp\php\hamad\app/config\services.yml (which is being imported fr
  om "C:\xampp\php\hamad\app/config\config.yml").

```
In DebugClassLoader.php line 293:
```

The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Resources\config\routing" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\php\hamad\vendor
  \composer/../../src/AppBundle\Resources\config\routing.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the cl
  ass name or namespace probably has a typo.

Suggestion would be welcomed to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please post the content of `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.php`? How do you call that code?

Comment: This is because you did an update and autowire/autoconfig is now enabled.  Basically, Symfony is trying to convert all your classes to services and assumes every php file is a class.  Of course, routing.php does not have a class.  Either disable autowire or add AppBundle/Resources to the excluded section in your services.yaml file.  Next time consider just searching for the first part of the error message.  Lots of identical questions.

Comment: I have Disable Autowire and the problem get solved , actually i have searched a'lot for the matching messages to users.Kindly Post it as an Answer that i should accept and thanks for sincere Interest in the Query.